# Remove "unit number" from street address strings

Tags: r, regex, string

I have two related questions.

**Question 1:** I have a column with a number of addresses. The addresses are either just the street name with no house number, a full address, and a full address with a unit number.

```
Fake St
100 Fake Street
Unit 1 200 Fake Street
Unit 2 200 Fake Street
```

I need assistance on creating a regex expression where I can remove the "Unit" phrase. My example would become:

```
Fake St
100 Fake Street
200 Fake Street
200 Fake Street
```

**Question 2:** For my streets that have no house number (e.g., "Fake St"), I want to create a new column that flags these. How would I go about doing this?

```
Fake St -> 1
100 Fake Street -> 0
200 Fake Street -> 0
200 Fake Street -> 0
```

Comment: You should ask just one question at a time on this site. Do you just want to literally remove the work "Unit" followed by a space and then any sequence of digits? Maybe something like `gsub("Unit \d+ ", "", addresses)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, `sub` provides one option:

```
x <- c("Fake St", "100 Fake Street", "Unit 1 200 Fake Street", "Unit 2 200 Fake Street")
out <- trimws(sub("\\s*Unit \\d+\\s*", " ", x))
out

[1] "Fake St"         "100 Fake Street" "200 Fake Street" "200 Fake Street"
```

For the second part:

```
flag <- as.numeric(!grepl("\\b\\d+\\b", out))
flag

[1] 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: How would this look like to be inclusive of letter characters instead of just numeric characters after "Unit"? For example, "Unit A".

Comment: For a more general solution consider using the pattern `\s*Unit \S+\s*`, but keep the rest of my script the same.